# Excel macro doesn't update upon being modified

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Please see attahced file: [the excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar0y71vBm1oLe6Hkq0IkF54MQIs)
I have a table in Sheet1. At the end of each row, I'd like to have a button with a macro assigned to it that if the first cell of the row equals "Sheet2", it fills out data from that row into some cells in Sheet2. 
If the first row says "Sheet3", it fills out data from that row into some cells in Sheet3. 
So what I did was to first record a macro like below:

```
Sub fill()
'
' fill Macro
'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("D3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

then I tried to make it conditional as:

```
Sub fill()
'
' fill Macro
'
If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Sheet2" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-1]C"
    Range("D3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

but the problem is that the if clause is not executed! No matter what value A1 has, it keeps filling out Sheet2 like there is no condition! I save and Run too. Please advise me on where I'm mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: You could try setting a breakpoint and making sure it gets hit. You might have two versions of the macro and you're not running the one you think you are. When it seems like our code is doing something impossible, that almost always means that some assumption - like which code is actually getting executed - is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Even if I delete the middle lines of fill function, it still does what was in the original function. I think it keeps it somewhere in a cache or something and executes that. I even right click on the button and make sure it is assigned the updated macro but still upon execution, the original old macro is executed!!!

Comment: If you write Sheet2 into Sheet1's cell A1, it works fine. Not what you desire, but it writes the formulas to Sheet2, if anything else is in A1 it does nothing. Just like you wrote it. There are different ways to create a button. How do you create one (in short)? And how many of those will you create?

Comment: Thanks. No matter what I write in A1, it executes the original fill function without if clause. Even when I delete half of the function, it still executes the original! I created the bottom from developer tab->insert->button then right click on it and assign the macro to it and before assigning, I check edit to make sure it's the macro I had in mine but regardless, it executes the original function!!!

Comment: As @ScottHannen suggested (and it seems you missed when reading his comment), set a breakpoint and step through the code, Does the breakpoint stop when you expect? Is the code that is executing what you expect? If not, you've got two copies of your code. If it steps into the proper code, you can see what is making it not run the code you're expecting. We can't run your code in the debuger for you, because we don't have the spreadsheet with the content to do so.

Comment: I just uploaded the file. No I tried breakpoint and even tried deleting lines too but couldn't figure out where the hidden version of the code is!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell` will tell you what range the button is that you just clicked.
From there you can get the sheet name in column A and send the info over there.

### The Code

```
Sub Rng_Butn_Clicked()
    Dim BtRng As Range, sh As Worksheet, rw As Long

    Set BtRng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell

    MsgBox BtRng.Address    'remove later
    MsgBox Cells(BtRng.Row, 1).Value    'remove later

    Set sh = Sheets(Cells(BtRng.Row, 1).Value)

    With sh
        rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(rw, 2).Value = Cells(BtRng.Row, 2).Value
        .Cells(rw, 3).Value = Cells(BtRng.Row, 3).Value
        .Cells(rw, 4).Value = Cells(BtRng.Row, 4).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Add the button from the Forms toolbox into the first cell, and assign the macro to that button. You can do it to the first cell then drag the cells down to copy the buttons.

[image]
[image]

Click the button and the code will send the data to the correct sheet.
The code has two msgboxes, you can remove them, it is just to show you what is happening